# Struts Pass Login Screen Form Data To Next Page Action

Tags: struts

Basically I have your standard login page for a struts application.

You enter password and Username and post back to the server, whilst moving onto the main application page.

I have java code within the main page that requires the login data from the last page to populate the table on screen. I have tried ActionRedirect but it keeps bring back nullpointerexception:

```
ActionRedirect redirect =
new ActionRedirect(mapping.findForward(SUCCESS));
redirect.addParameter("userName",loginForm.getUserName());
return redirect;
```

here is the struts config:

```
<action input="/login.jsp" name="LoginForm" path="/Login" scope="request"     type="com.myapp.struts.LoginAction" validate="false">
        <result name="success" type="redirect-action">
            <param name="location">/timesheet.jsp</param>
            <param name="parse">false</param>
          </result>
          <forward name="failure" path="/login.jsp" />
    </action>
```

and the error comes back as:

```
WARNING: Unable to find 'timesheet.jsp' forward.
```

and yes I have tried to add another forward relating to 'SUCCESS' but again it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Struts config was missing forward, had put the result section within the forward param and thats why its wasnt working

Comment: What are you even *talking* about? Your "config" file mixes Struts 1 and Struts 2 and the app wouldn't even start up like that.